# Customize plot with CapForm?

Tags: plotting, graphics, style, plot-themes

Simple plotting question: I'd like to keep the base style of the "Business" theme, but with two slight modifications:

- Use `CapForm` to round the ends of my plot curve
- Override the `Frame` option so I have a y axis frame too

Here's the code:

```
bceLoss = -(#Target*Log[#Input] + (1 - #Target)*Log[1 - #Input]) &;
Plot[Evaluate@bceLoss[<|"Input" -> p, "Target" -> 1|>], {p, 0, 1}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Probability of Ground Truth Class", "Loss"}, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, PlotTheme -> "Business"]
```

[image]

Comment: `PlotStyle -> CapForm["Round"]` works for me. I don't know how to force the `Frame`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, `PlotStyle -> CapForm["Round"]` will take care of that requirement.

For the frame, you can combine the `"Business"` theme with `"FullAxes"` by enclosing them in a list:

```
bceLoss = -(#Target*Log[#Input] + (1 - #Target)*Log[1 - #Input]) &;
Plot[Evaluate@bceLoss[<|"Input" -> p, "Target" -> 1|>], {p, 0, 1}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Probability of Ground Truth Class", "Loss"}, 
 PlotStyle -> CapForm["Round"], PlotTheme -> {"Business", "FullAxes"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can find the `Frame` and `FrameStyle` settings associated with the `"Business"` theme using

```
{Frame, FrameStyle} /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Business", Plot]
```

> {{{True, False}, {True, False}},
>       {{StrokeForm[Opacity[0]], StrokeForm[Opacity[0]]}, {Automatic, None}}}

So, you need to override the `FrameStyle` set by the `PlotTheme` by using, say,

```
FrameStyle -> {{Opacity[1], Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}
```

to get (after adding `PlotStyle -> CapForm["Round"]` as suggested by Szabolcs):

[image]